# How do I write a Clone SUMIF Function in VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lately, as a means of quenching my curiosity, I'm trying to understand how Native Excel Functions would work if they were written in VBA Language.
One such function I was working on was `SUMIF`

I was able to write the code to replicate  exact functioning of SUMIF only if the criteria was an "Equal to" `=` Operator. I'm stuck as to how to change the code so as to accommodate other operators such as `>=`, `<=` etc.

Here's what I have developed so far.

```
Function SUMIF_VBA(Crit_Rng As Range, Condition_U As Variant, Sum_Rng As Range)

R_Offset = Sum_Rng.Row - Crit_Rng.Row
C_Offset = Sum_Rng.Column - Crit_Rng.Column

SUMIF_VBA = 0

For Each Cell In Crit_Rng

If Cell.Value = Condition_U Then
SUMIF_VBA = SUMIF_VBA + Cell.Offset(R_Offset, C_Offset).Value

End If

Next Cell

End Function
```

As you know SUMIF Dynamically arranges for Operators
Eg:

```
SUMIF(A:A,>=10,C:C)
```

This code will automatically calculate the sum of values in C Column, if their corresponding A Column values are greater than or equal to 10.

I wanted to include the same functionality in my SUMIF Code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use Evaluate statement, see if that works for you.

Comment: It would be good to write the functionality in 2 parts - one part takes the if conditional, and the last part can be a aggregate function over the result set. This would allow the easier use of other funcs to be easily implemented i.e. Averageif, medianif, etc. Also I would not use couple logic in the function(no Offset - treat the input ranges as data arrays on their own merit and reference them)

Comment: Also, why not write a parser for the condition argument, so that various inputs can be recognised and used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possibility. It does not use Evaluate as you had requested.

```
Function SUMIF_VBA(Crit_Rng As Range, Condition_U As Variant, Sum_Rng As Range)

R_Offset = Sum_Rng.Row - Crit_Rng.Row
C_Offset = Sum_Rng.Column - Crit_Rng.Column

SUMIF_VBA = 0

Call ParseCondition(Condition_U, Cond_out, Criteria_out)
For Each Cell In Crit_Rng

SumThis = False
Select Case Cond_out
    Case 3
        If Cell.Value = Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
    Case 5
        If Cell.Value > Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
    Case 7
        If Cell.Value < Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
    Case 8
        If Cell.Value >= Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
    Case 10
        If Cell.Value <= Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
    Case 12
        If Cell.Value <> Criteria_out Then
            SumThis = True
        End If
End Select

If SumThis Then
    SUMIF_VBA = SUMIF_VBA + Cell.Offset(R_Offset, C_Offset).Value
End If

Next Cell

End Function

Private Sub ParseCondition(Cond_in, Cond_out, Criteria_out)

    '* Evaluate the condition and set a unique number on each condition
    Cond_out = 0
    If InStr(Cond_in, "=") Then
      Cond_out = Cond_out + 3
    End If

    If InStr(Cond_in, ">") Then
      Cond_out = Cond_out + 5
    End If

    If InStr(Cond_in, "<") Then
      Cond_out = Cond_out + 7
    End If

    Set SDI = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    SDI.Pattern = "\d+"  '* keep the number only
    Set Num_out = SDI.Execute(Cond_in)
    Criteria_out = Val(Num_out(0))


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you help me understand what these lines of code mean ? 


`Set SDI = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    SDI.Pattern = "\d+"  '* keep the number only
    Set Num_out = SDI.Execute(Cond_in)
    Criteria_out = Val(Num_out(0)) `

Comment: This is called a regular expression. Many modern languages have this functionality. Regular expressions use the pattern to parse a string. In this case, "\d+" returns the numbers from a string, but it returns it in a data structure and as a text literal. SO, Num_out(0) gets to the value returned by the SDI.Execute statement and Val converts it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Check out!

```
Function test_sumif(c_a As Range, c_b As String, c_c As Range)
n = 1

For Each r In c_a

If Application.Evaluate(r.Value & c_b) Then
 test_sumif = test_sumif + c_c(n, 1).Value
End If

n = n + 1
Next

End Function
```

It is as close to the functionality as the original sumif function. Didn't handle the optional sumrange part though.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. 
`Application.Evaluate` would work on places where there is ">=" or any other logical operator.
However, it will not work if there isn't any. But that can be fixed using `InStr` Function to recognize when there is an operator and when there isn't.
However the bigger problem is that Application.Evaluate does not compare two string.
For eg. B>A is not something Application.Evaluate is able to compare.
Whereas SUMIF does that.
Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas:

```
'This function returns the filtered array to the caller, so that it may sum, concat, average or whatever
Private Function GetFilteredArray(leftArgRange As Range, condition As Variant, Optional sumRange As Range) As Variant()
    Dim sumArray() As Variant, leftArgArray() As Variant

    If leftArgRange.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        leftArgArray = Intersect(leftArgRange.Worksheet.UsedRange, leftArgRange).Value2
    ElseIf leftArgRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        leftArgArray = Array(leftArgRange.Cells(1, 1).Value2)
    Else
        Exit Function   'return empty array
    End If

    If sumRange Is Nothing Then
        sumArray = leftArgArray
    Else
        sumArray = Intersect(sumRange.Worksheet.UsedRange, sumRange).Value2
    End If

    Dim filteredArr() As Variant
    ReDim filteredArr(0 To leftArgRange.Cells.Count - 1)

    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, filteredCount As Long

    For i = LBound(leftArgArray) To UBound(leftArgArray)
        For j = LBound(leftArgArray, 2) To UBound(leftArgArray, 2)
            If Compare(leftArgArray(i, j), condition) Then
                filteredArr(filteredCount) = sumArray(i, j)
                filteredCount = filteredCount + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    If filteredCount > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve filteredArr(0 To filteredCount - 1)
        GetFilteredArray = filteredArr
    End If

End Function

Private Function Compare(leftArg As Variant, condition As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rightArg As Variant
    If VarType(condition) = vbString Then
        'parse String
        If condition Like ">=*" Then
            rightArg = Mid(condition, 3)
            Compare = leftArg >= IIf(IsNumeric(rightArg), CDec(rightArg), rightArg)
        ElseIf condition Like "<=*" Then
            rightArg = Mid(condition, 3)
            Compare = leftArg <= IIf(IsNumeric(rightArg), CDec(rightArg), rightArg)
        ElseIf condition Like ">*" Then
            rightArg = Mid(condition, 2)
            Compare = leftArg > IIf(IsNumeric(rightArg), CDec(rightArg), rightArg)
        ElseIf condition Like "<*" Then
            rightArg = Mid(condition, 2)
            Compare = leftArg < IIf(IsNumeric(rightArg), CDec(rightArg), rightArg)
        ElseIf condition Like "**LIKE**" Then
            rightArg = Mid(condition, 7)
            Compare = InStr(1, leftArg, rightArg, vbTextCompare) > 0
        Else
            'assume equals
            rightArg = condition
            Compare = leftArg = rightArg
        End If
    Else
        'assume other primitive/struct such as Date, numeric, boolean etc
        rightArg = condition
        Compare = leftArg = rightArg
    End If

End Function
```

Call from worksheet:

```
Public Function VBA_SUMIF(leftArgRange As Range, condition As Variant, Optional sumRange As Range) As Double
    Dim filteredArr() As Variant
    filteredArr = GetFilteredArray(leftArgRange, condition, sumRange)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long, total As Double
    For i = LBound(filteredArr) To UBound(filteredArr)
        total = total + filteredArr(i)
    Next i

    VBA_SUMIF = total
End Function

Public Function VBA_CONCATIF(leftArgRange As Range, condition As Variant, Optional sumRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String = "") As String
    Dim filteredArr() As Variant
    filteredArr = GetFilteredArray(leftArgRange, condition, sumRange)

    VBA_CONCATIF = Join(filteredArr, delimiter)
End Function

Public Function VBA_COUNTIF(leftArgRange As Range, condition As Variant) As Long
    Dim filteredArr() As Variant
    filteredArr = GetFilteredArray(leftArgRange, condition)

    On Error Resume Next
    VBA_COUNTIF = UBound(filteredArr) - LBound(filteredArr) + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many worksheet functions within *VBA*.  Say our data is like:

[image]

We put in a standard module:

```
Public Function Vsumif(crrange As Range, crit As String, which As Range)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Vsumif = .SumIf(crrange, crit, which)
    End With
End Function
```

and then in some cell, enter:

```
=vsumif(A:A,">=10",C:C)
```

and it will yield the proper result.

To use the *UDF()* within a sub:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim x As Variant

    x = Vsumif(Range("A:A"), ">=10", Range("C:C"))
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying.
What I am actually looking for is the code behind this without using any of the worksheet functions.
As I said before this is just out of curiosity. I've just started learning programming and an important part is being able to understand how to structure codes to achieve results. Hence, I wanted a solution purely from VBA point of view without any assistance of Worksheet Function. Would really appreciate if you could help me out with that.